# error : exec x in pypdfocr in python

Tags: python, exec, evernote

How can i solve this problem, I am getting the exec x error in evernote/setup.py while installing pypdfocr in python

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error "**exec x**" while installing **pypdfocr** then just follow some steps and you will be able to install pypdfocr.

Just download the whl file of **evernote** just replace the "**exec x**" in setup.py by "**exec(x)**" and then run setup.py.

After installing evernote install pypdfocr on version3.x of python. It will be installed successfully.

Thank you

Comment: `exec x` is correct Python 2. It is incorrect in Python 3 and if you try it you get the error *Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'.* This indicates that you are installing a Python 2 module in Python 3. That Python 2 `exec` statement is unlikely to be the only version incompatibility that you encounter.